# C++ RapidJSON parse a JSON object wrapped in a callback function

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

i'm trying to parse a JSON response from Yahoo API using RapidJSON library in C++ , and this response is wrapped in a callback method.
This is the response i'm getting

```
YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks({"ResultSet":{"Query":"AMZN","Result":[{"symbol":"AMZN","name":"Amazon.com, Inc.","exch":"NMS","type":"S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"AMZN.MX","name":"Amazon.com, Inc.","exch":"MEX","type":"S","exchDisp":"Mexico","typeDisp":"Equity"}]}});
```

If i feed this JSON response directly to RapidJSON like this it cannot parse it.

```
rapidjson::Document json_doc;

if (json_doc.Parse(fetched_data.c_str()).HasParseError()) {
        continue;
}
```

So what is the method to parse the JSON with this callback function portion `YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks` other than the obvious way to delete this substring altogether.

Comment: This is actually not a JSON but [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). RapidJSON has no support for that because it is not a standard. You shall remove the paddings in order to convert it to a standard JSON.

Comment: Oh i remember now JSONP, JSON with Padding. Yes i understand that its not in the standard specifications, so i removed the padding manually as guided by David Haims post. But thank you for providing this wonderful , fast and light tool for parsing JSON in C++. Very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can psuedo-null the `);` part and give a pointer to just after the callback part:

```
size_t pos = std::string("YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks(").size();
std::string stringifiedJSON = "YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks({"ResultSet": /*...*/ });"
str[str.size() - 2] = 0; // null terminate exactly on ");"
const char* ptr = stringifiedJSON.data();
ptr += pos;
json::Document doc;
doc.parse(ptr);
str[str.size() - 2] = ')'; //revert the string back;
```

Comment: Yes this is the most obvious way to solve this as RapidJSON doesn't seem to be capable of parsing such callback wrapped JSON. Thanks for your reply. Appreciate it.